# Regex match word in a text but not in quotes or comments

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'am building extension for VS Code and use formatter API to capitalize all keywords.

Let's say I have code in an editor.

```
TYPE MyStruct : STRUCT
        this.var1 : POINTER TO INT; (* Указатель 1 *)
        var2 : POINTER TO INT; (* this is Указатель 2 *)
        sStr: STRING(200) := "This 
            Test this line";    
        sStr: STRING(200) := "Test this line";    
        sStr: STRING(200) := 'Test this line';    
    END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

THIS.MyStruct := 100;
```

I want to find all `this` words but on in comments `(* ... *)` or strings (in single or double quotes)?

My attempt is this with ig

```
(?<=^([^"'])*)\bthis\b
```

but it still select in comments and if there is new line.

This is my real code example

```
let keywords = [
    'true', 'false', 'exit', 'continue', 'return', 'constant', 'retain',
    'public', 'private', 'protected', 'abstract','persistent','internal',
    'final','of','else','elsif','then','__try','__catch','__finally',
    '__endtry','do','to','by','task','with','using','uses','from',
    'until','or','or_else','and','and_then','not','xor','nor','ge',
    'le','eq','ne','gt','lt','__new','__delete', 'extends','implements',
    'this','super'
];
let regEx = new RegExp(`\\b(?:${keywords.join('|')}|AT|BOOL|BYTE|(?:D|L)?WORD|U?(?:S|D|L)?INT|L?REAL|TIME(?:_OF_DAY)?|TOD|DT|DATE(?:_AND_TIME)?|STRING|ARRAY|ANY)\\b`, "ig");
text = text.replace(regEx, (match) => {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: You can simply add a check to find all the this. or this( because that is how this keyword is used.

Comment: please add your attempt in question even if it is not working

Comment: @MubashirEbad  this is a simple example. real task is much more complex includes hundreds of keywords. The `this` is actualy another complex regex. I simplified task but I cannot use your suggestions. Some keywords are functions ABS, MOD, some keys EXIT, REURN, some properties and some parameters and so one. So `\b(my keywords)\b` is working fine, I only need to add exeptions in strings and comments.

Comment: @anubhava added.

Comment: You may use this regex: `/\(\*[^]*?\*\)|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|(\bthis\b)/gi` and your matched text will be available in capture group #1. See demo: https://regex101.com/r/oC0lPY/1

Comment: @anubhava why `\\.` and not `\.`? and what is ```\\``` for?

Comment: @anubhava I added my real code example

Comment: @anubhava I made some experiment. VS code do not need capture pattern it even works with uncaptured patterns `(?:` It now capitalize comments and strings. I guess I can only use look behind or ahead.

Comment: `\\.` is used for the case when you have an escaped `"` or `'` inside a quoted string e.g. `'Cat\'s eye'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the contexts you need to discard, and then match and capture those occurrences of your pattern that you need to modify:

```
/(?<!\\(?:\\{2})*)"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^\\"]*)*"|\(\*[\s\S]*?\*\)|\b(true|false|exit|continue|return|constant|retain|public|private|protected|abstract|persistent|internal|final|of|else|elsif|then|__try|__catch|__finally|__endtry|do|to|by|task|with|using|uses|from|until|or|or_else|and|and_then|not|xor|nor|ge|le|eq|ne|gt|lt|__new|__delete|extends|implements|this|super|AT|BOOL|BYTE|(?:D|L)?WORD|U?(?:S|D|L)?INT|L?REAL|TIME(?:_OF_DAY)?|TOD|DT|DATE(?:_AND_TIME)?|STRING|ARRAY|ANY)\b/gi
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8FhsRN/1).

I changed the first `(?:` in your pattern to `(` so that your expected match is captured into Group 1, and added `(?<!\\(?:\\{2})*)"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^\\"]*)*"|\(\*[\s\S]*?\*\)|` at the start of the pattern:

- `(?<!\\(?:\\{2})*)"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^\\"]*)*"` - a location not preceded with a backslash optionally followed with any even amount of backslashes and then  a double quoted string with escape sequence support
- `|` - or
- `\(\*[\s\S]*?\*\)` - `(*`, then any 0+ chars, as few as possible and then `*)`.

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const keywords = [
    'true', 'false', 'exit', 'continue', 'return', 'constant', 'retain',
    'public', 'private', 'protected', 'abstract','persistent','internal',
    'final','of','else','elsif','then','__try','__catch','__finally',
    '__endtry','do','to','by','task','with','using','uses','from',
    'until','or','or_else','and','and_then','not','xor','nor','ge',
    'le','eq','ne','gt','lt','__new','__delete', 'extends','implements',
    'this','super'
];
const regEx = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<!\\(?:\\{2})*)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|\(\*.*?\*\)|\b(${keywords.join('|')}|AT|BOOL|BYTE|(?:D|L)?WORD|U?(?:S|D|L)?INT|L?REAL|TIME(?:_OF_DAY)?|TOD|DT|DATE(?:_AND_TIME)?|STRING|ARRAY|ANY)\b`, "igs");
let text = "TYPE MyStruct : STRUCT\n        this.var1 : POINTER TO INT; (* Указатель 1 *)\n        var2 : POINTER TO INT; (* this is Указатель 2 *)\n        sStr: STRING(200) := \"This \n            Test this line\";    \n        sStr: STRING(200) := \"Test this line\";    \n        sStr: STRING(200) := 'Test this line';    \n    END_STRUCT\nEND_TYPE\n\nTHIS.MyStruct := 100;";
text = text.replace(regEx, (match,group) => {
    return group != undefined ? match.toUpperCase() : match;
});
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Because of this concept I waa able to reduce my code from 130 lines to only 70. Thank you. I completely forgot that I replace it. I so getused to VS Code syntax file where you obly define regex but have no power over how it is parced, I forgot that I can evaluate every match.